# What kind of Design is this? Lowpoly or polymer or something else?

Tags: interface-design, style-identification, graphic-styles

[image]

I want to know what kind of design is this? Low poly or polymer or something else?

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [Google Cardboard Design Lab - design style](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/73444/23061)

Comment: Can you please provide some additional examples of the style you're referencing? As is, there are a lot of techniques used in the image above

Answer (score 2):

this is a **lowpoly illustration.**

A simple google search shows similar photos

[image]